# Need Help in services running in background

Tags: android, service, android-service

I need to create a background service like when user is trying to open any of the installed application, let him know that application's information (eg: Package-name) before that application begins to starts.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this isn't possible unless a) the app is a launcher, which can show a notification before starting applications, or b) the app requires root access -- something I'm assuming you don't want.

For Android, it would be a serious issue if a service could stop the user from opening apps: the service could start on boot, and then no other apps could be opened to shut it down, rendering the device useless.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ya somewhat agreed with you but if we take example of app-locker then it would asks to enter password before getting start to any application.. i hope you getting me.. thnks for reply

Comment: Interesting... can you by chance grab the startactivity intent before the application launches?

Comment: Nope i think we can't grab intent this way..! but their should be something which is going to launch while starting any app and we need to grad that think..

Answer (score 0):

**you can create services by this way ::**

```
package com.Touch;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class BackServices extends Service {


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    }

}
```

and you can get install ap information by this :: 
http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon

Comment: thnks for resopding.. well ur above code is showing just mockup of creating services .. nd the link u provided is for getting list of installed applications.. So u may wondering that i use that code of getting package list in above service ri8???....but how can i detect that which application user wants to open?.... plzz if not getting me than plz read my post again i tried best to explain my query in this comment or in post.. nd if posiable thn plz help as soon as u can..thnks

Comment: I tried my best for it but i can't thats y i posted here..! if u get my answer thn please publish it as soon as u can..